# Perl multiple pattern matching and substitution in one pass

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

```
09/27/2009 19:48:00 Departure Location
```

I am trying to match and substitute the given line in a text file. The length of the text after date and time can vary. I am reading the file line by line and I need the final output to be printed as--

```
Date=> 09/27/2009
Time=> 19:48:00 
Text=> Departure Location
```

I have tried to do the substitutions in one pass as follows-

```
if($line =~ m/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\h{1}(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/){

    $line =~ s/(\[a-zA-Z])/\nText=> $1/;
    $line =~ s/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/\nDate=> $1\/$2\/$3/;
    $line =~ s/\h{1}(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/\nTime=> $1\:$2\:$3/;

    print FH "$line\n";

}
```

But all I am getting is this-

```
Date=> 09/27/2009
Time=> 19:48:10 Departure Location
```

I know there is a problem in matching the `Text` but I am not able to fix it. I am still a Perl beginner. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern in particular is giving you trouble:

```
$line =~ s/(\[a-zA-Z])/\nText=> $1/;
```

There are a few problems with it.  First, the backslash in front of the left bracket:  `\[`, is escaping the bracket so that your character class isn't a character class at all, but rather the literal text, "`[a-zA-Z]`".  Second, there is no "whitespace" permitted in your text match, so if the text portion of the string contains any space characters, (or punctuation) it will also fail to match.  Third, there is no quantifier, so it will only match a single character.  A final note is that it should probably be anchored to the end of the string.  It might work like this (but don't use it, read on instead):

```
$line =~ s/([a-zA-Z\s]+)$/\nText=> $1/;
```

But there's probably a better solution.  It can all be done in one pass without losing clarity.  To me it starts to make more sense if you capture larger segments:

```
$string =~ s{^
    (\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})\s    # The date.
    (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s     # The time.
    (.+)$                  # The rest (the text).
}{Date=> $1\nTime=> $2\nText=> $3}x;
```

As is usually the case, the /x modifier facilitates easier to read code.

There are some good resources available for getting a handle on Perl's regular expressions.  I would suggest starting with [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), which is "a basic tutorial on understanding, creating and using regular expressions in Perl."

Using named captures can also add a degree of clarity, especially as your regexes become more complex:

```
$string =~ s{
    ^
    (?<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})\s
    (?<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s
    (?<text>.+)
    $
}
{Date=> $+{date}\nTime=> $+{time}\nText=> $+{text}}x;
```

Comment: Nice, DavidO.  Given the line--and your data caveat--this also works: `s/(\S+) (\S+) (.*)/Date=> $1\nTime=> $2\nText=> $3\n/`

Comment: @Kenosis yes, that would also work.  I tend to favor more explicit matches so that I get as few false-positives as practical, and so that I can maintain finer control of where in the string the match occurs, but your method does work too.

Comment: Your regex rationale makes good sense, and your added named captures helps with readability.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Though I could not improve on my solution even after your suggestion. +1 for adding a degree of clarity. I am not exactly sure about the usage of '/x' modifier. Can you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: The /x modifier allows you to freely use space and comments (except within character classes) in your regular expression.  Spaces and comments are treated almost the same as they would be treated outside of a regular expression where you use them for code formatting.  This allows you to add indentation, formatting, and comments to your regular expressions to improve their readability.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#/x

Answer (score 5):

[split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) with a limit would work nicely here. The `pairwise` is not strictly necessary, but helped me avoid a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw( pairwise );

my $input = q{09/27/2009 19:48:00 Departure Location};
my @fields = qw(Date Time Text);
my @values = split ' ', $input, @fields;

{
    no warnings 'once';
    say join("\n", pairwise { "$a=> $b" } @fields, @values);
}
```

Output:

```
Date=> 09/27/2009
Time=> 19:48:00
Text=> Departure Location
```

Comment: I tried to split it earlier but was having difficulty in extracting it from the @array as my integer variable(numeric) could not contain time values. Well, now I know the right way. Thank you. +1 for doing it neatly and beautifully! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing too much work in your parser.

```
my ($date, $time, $text) = split(' ', $_, 3);
say "Date=> $date";
say "Time=> $time";
say "Text=> $text";
```

Comment: I think you misread the OP's target string. (updated comment)

Comment: Oh! I got the input and output backwards. Fixed.

Comment: (If you want to validate the date, the time and the text, do it after the split)

Comment: Someday someone's going to add a timezone to that timestamp, delimited by a space, and all of our solutions will break. ;)  ...if not in this specific case, in the general case at least.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said "**all** of our solutions".  :)  At some point you just have to go with it, and move on.  Anyway, I like the split suggestions.

Comment: It's the simplest so far! I was confused with how to do it with a split. Though I would need to add an `if` earlier to check if I am parsing the right line because my file contains some other data too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Cramming as much functionality into a small space only contributes to the reputation Perl has for being incomprehensible.

This code seems much clearer to me

```
$line = <<END if $line =~ m|^(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}) \s+ (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \s+ (.*)|x;
Date=> $1
Time=> $2 
Text=> $3
END
```

Comment: I didn't get the first line, what does '<<' keyword do?

Comment: That's a "HERE" document.  The lines following `<<END`, through (but not including) `END` are quoted using "double-quotish" semantics.  See perlop under the "Quote and Quote-Like Operators" section.

Comment: The one tricky thing here is that usually we are accustomed to seeing `<<END;`.  The inclusion of an `if` modifier could be a little confusing if you're unfamiliar with how here-docs work, and where the actual quoted text begins.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to get familiar with it. Right now I guess I will put more emphasis on clear and neat code. Now I got a variety of solutions to try though :)

Comment: @Prince: [Quote-Like Operators](https://metacpan.org/module/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) describes the "here-document" syntax.